# HTML native app not fitting correctly landscape mode on large sized phones. Can't force to fit

Tags: android, css, apk, phonegap-build, phonegap

New to the forum.

I have a native calculator app that was created in html to run in landscape mode for both iOS and Android.  I use Phonegap Build to create my apps.  It worked fine initially a few years back but with the new phones, it does not display properly on these larger plus size phones.  The width works fine but in order to see the last row of buttons, you have to scroll down a row which then takes out the input display.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to make this fit in depth.  Works fine with tablets since these are wider.

I currently use this viewport and I have played around with others but not fixing the problem.

I have tinkered with everything in the .css files and html and can not get this to work.  Driving me crazy.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Attached is a picture of what it should look like and the other picture is what it get on my Note 9 and other large screen phones.  This is happening with Android.  I haven't got to the iOS stuff yet.

Here is what I need to show:

[image]

Here is what is showing.  Missing the bottom line.  Have to scroll down to see it but then can't see display:

[image]

Comment: Please share code snippet for example.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance.  Which code are you referring to?  The html or css or both?...Thank you for your response.